# How to cleanup my urls using .htaccess files?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My URL's look like this:

- http://www.example.com/Admin/This_Admin.php?status=changesSaved
- http://www.example.com/Admin/This_Admin.php?action=Edit_Article&articleId=1

I'd like it to show like  this:

- http://www.example.com/Admin/This_Admin.php
- http://www.example.com/Admin/This_Admin.php

These are my rewrite rules that I have tried so far:

```
RewriteRule ^Admin.php/([^/]+)/?$ /?action=Edit_Article&articleId=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^Admin.php/([^/\.]+)/?status=changesSaved [L]
```

The point is to not have these pages as a link even for admin. The default should always be This_Admin.php as far as the admin pages go.

Comment: How is your web server supposed to know which `http://www.example.com/Admin/This_Admin.php` the user is trying to access if the same URL is going to two different URLs?

Comment: @TonyM0str0 use POST method instead of GET and u wont have to redirect anything

Comment: @ceejayoz - I'm not changing the links in the documents just the way the links are displayed. I had this working before but all that was years ago and I'm just back getting into it again. Sad part is I have no access to those files anymore. A lot of hard work I put into what I've created and it's gone. I'm just now establishing my setup again.